# Safest way to copy an attribute from one las file to another?

Tags: r, lidar, las, lidr

I have two modified las files, which came from the same original las file. One of the files (file A) was produced using [normalize_height()](https://rdrr.io/cran/lidR/man/normalize_height.html) and the other (file B) was produced using [normalize_intensity()](https://rdrr.io/cran/lidR/man/normalize_intensity.html). So the two las files come from the same parent las file, only they have normalized heights and normalized intensities respectively. I would like to copy the normalized intensity values from file B to file A. Is there a way to this with [add_attribute()](https://rdrr.io/cran/lidR/man/add_attribute.html)
while ensuring that each point get's the correct normalized intensity value? Should both files first be sorted or something like that?

**UPDATE:**
It seems that [normalize_height()](https://rdrr.io/cran/lidR/man/normalize_height.html) removes a few points from file A, making a match without filtering file B impossible...

```
add_lasattribute(norm_las, rc_las@data$Intensity, "CorrectedIntensity", "intensity values as a result of range correction")
#> Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, name, value = c(13L, 13L, 161L, 150L,  : 
  replacement has 28380609 rows, data has 28380265
npoints(norm_las)
#>[1] 28380265
npoints(rc_las)
#>[1] 28380609
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point ordering is expected to be preserved. Unless you explicitly discarded / rearranged / split some points the following should work.

```r
las2$Intensity = las1$Intensity
```

But you could also chain the operations. `normalize_intensity()` should come first because it requires absolute elevations:

```r
las = normalize_intensity(las, ...)
las = normalize_height(las, ...)
```

`normalize_height()` discards some points only if `na.rm = TRUE`. If for some reason you have already normalized and discarded some points you can always perform a join with `data.table` native syntax

```r
# simulate intensity normalized dataset
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
las1 = readLAS(LASfile)
las1$Intensity = as.integer(runif(npoints(las1), 0,500))

# Simulate height normalized dataset with missing points
las2 = readLAS(LASfile, filter = "-keep_random_fraction 0.98")

# join on XY ReturnNumber (and/or gpstime) 
joined = las1@data[, .(X,Y,ReturnNumber, Intensity)][las2@data[, .(X,Y,ReturnNumber)], on = .(X,Y,ReturnNumber)]

# Update intensity
las2$Intensity = joined$Intensity
```

Comment: Chaining is definitely the more simple approach. The reason for this question is that I have a large set of files which have already been height normalized. I was hoping to save some processing time by avoiding reapplying `normalize_height()`... But since I didn't run this function with `na.rm = FALSE` I think my only choice is to re-run `normalize_height()`. Do you agree?

Comment: Actually, I ran the old `lasnormalize()` function with default parameters for `na.rm`. So it is likely that the few hundred points that were removed were "degenerated" right? I don't think there is any way around this.

Comment: Degenerated points are not expected to be removed. No point is expected to be removed actually. If you have fewer points after normalization you either found a bug of forgot that you performed some extra post-processing

Comment: The documentation for the `Wdegenerated` parameter under the `normalize_height()` documentation implies that degenerated points are removed.

Comment: Now you are saying, the documentation is very misleading. Degenerated ground points are removed for the computation of the DTM to avoid degenerated behaviors but degenerated points are normalized like any other points and are present in the output.

Comment: Ok thank you for clarifying. Yes sorry, the degenerated points comment was a bit of a detour from the original question. The `data.table` style join seems like the solution I'm looking for. I can't join on `Z` since one file will have normalized heights and the other will  not, but I think I can get unique keys with `X, Y, gpstime, ReturnNumber`. Thank you!

Comment: Exact, my bad. You can indeed use gpstime and/or return number

Comment: Interestingly it is sometimes required to round the X, and Y values (projection in meters) to at least 8 decimal places to produce a match. Not sure why this is, but rounding seems to work despite giving me pause...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116345/discussion-between-jrr-and-lucas).